# Save information using Unit Of Work and different targets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, design-patterns, unit-of-work

I have a command in my .NET webservice which needs to save information in several different places:

- 1 local database SQL Server using Entity Framework
- 2 different webservices using REST

I would like to use the Unit Of Work pattern.  It's easy when you only have a database and work with the data context.

But do you have any idea how I can implement a Unit Of Work with mixed targets?  I know that I cannot rely on a distributed transaction and I can live without.  But the principle of Unit Of Work is something I would like to keep.

Any idea, advice or pattern I could use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mix the database save logic with the REST save logic. You can leave the UoW module work exclusively with the database and add an additional service layer on top which utilize the UoW to save in the DB and after that invoke the REST endpoint to save there too. The service layer will orchestrate the different operations under common methods.

Can you provide some example code as to give you a more proper advice?

---

**EDIT**:

Okay, here is some generic example:

Here is your UnitOfWork class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
    private IDepartmentRepository departmentRepository;
    private ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public IDepartmentRepository DepartmentRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.departmentRepository == null)
            {
                this.departmentRepository = new DepartmentRepository(context);
            }
            return departmentRepository;
        }
    }

    public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.customerRepository == null)
            {
                this.customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(context);
            }
            return customerRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }

        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And a part of your service layer might look something like this:

```
class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public CustomerService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        this.unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.Add(customer);
        this.unitOfWork.Save();

        // Call REST here
    }

    public void DeleteCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        this.unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.DeleteById(customerId);
        this.unitOfWork.Save();

        // Call REST here
    }
}
```

In your controllers you operate exclusively through the Service layer. In the current example, you'll instantiate a new CustomerService if you want to Add/Delete customers, etc...

Have in mind that this is nearly a pseudo code and might not fit your needs precisely, but can't do much more without any information about your context.

Comment: I do not have code yet, as I'm busy working on the architecture design

Comment: @hugorgor Leave some feedback if this will fit your case.

Comment: Nice example but as expected, this is not very generic.  That was the purpose of my question.  But thanks for your sample!

Comment: @hugorgor Can you explain what exactly you mean by generic in your case? I mean, either share some of the context and the available cases or at least state what exactly you need to be more generic.